# Create separate pipelines using bicep

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I use YAML for creating separate pipelines for each environment (PRE-PROD, PROD). Is it possible to create separate pipelines using bicep?

Answer (score 0):

Azure bicep is used to provision infrastructure on Azure. This is not possible to create pipeline in Azure DevOps using bicep files.